# How to cancel/abort TCP IP Request in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, tcpclient

I have Tcp client and Server i can send request and get response each other with `SimpleTcp`  from [NuGET Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleTCP/)

I can send/receive Hexadecimal messages but I want to ask when i send request i want to abort it.

How can i abort request?

Here how i connect

```
    SimpleTcpClient client;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        client = new SimpleTcpClient();
        client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;

    }
```

With this function i'm sending request and i'm sending it on button click event

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
        client.WriteLineAndGetReply(request, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
```

Comment: The BCL has no `SimpleTcp` class. There are a *lot* of libraries called SimpleTcp. Which one are you using?

Comment: You are right let me cleriffy I'm using NuGET package @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using this [SimpleTcp](https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP) library, there is nothing to cancel the `WriteLineAndGetReply` method, it's waiting for either an answer or the timeout.

But the method is just subscribing to the `DataReceived` event, calling the `WriteLine` method, and using a loop to wait for a reply or the end of the timeout.

You can do the same, subscribe to the `DataReceived` event and wait for a reply or your own cancellation.

Check here https://github.com/BrandonPotter/SimpleTCP/blob/61f1932201a7c5633ad2f003c97c83c31541fc85/SimpleTCP/SimpleTcpClient.cs#L170
For the code sample on how it's done in the library.

Example adding a cancellation token to the existing method:

```
    public Message WriteLineAndGetReplyWithCancel(
        string data, 
        TimeSpan timeout, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Message mReply = null;
        this.DataReceived += (s, e) => { mReply = e; };
        WriteLine(data);

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        while (mReply == null && 
               sw.Elapsed < timeout &&
               !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        return mReply;
    }
```

You would use it like that:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;

WriteLineAndGetReplyWithCancel(request, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), token);

// To cancel
source.Cancel();
```

More information about cancellation token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks. Yes i'm using exactly that package but i'm really new at this topic. Can you give code example about this? I also saw thisgithub reference but not exactly understand. When i send request after client finishing thread and quit function how can i track timeout finish?

Comment: See my edit for an example of a reimplementation of the library's method with a cancellation token added.

Comment: Thanks @Gimly . I understand but one thing i can't clearify is I'm writing Server app and Client app when i send request you said wait and cancel it but i already send my request and getting response so how Server side understand to request cancelled  because when i send request after that i will send Cancel request too

Comment: This you'll have to manage on your server side, it gets outside the scope of your question. But if you have a long treatment on the server, you'll need to do something similar on your server to stop this long treatment.

Comment: I guess that is my question i asked wrong way. because i'm sending request via button click event and after that i want to click on Abort and Abort the request. That is the idea probably i asked wrong way sorry

Comment: Then you should be able to do it with the code I passed, storing the token source somewhere in your form and calling the `source.Cancel()` on this cancel button click. If you need to tell the server to also cancel the long running query, you should create another message that tells him to stop and do something similar with the cancellation token to stop the long running query.

Answer (score 0):

With bare [TcpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.8) you can call asynchronous methods on [NetworkStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netframework-4.8) which take [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netcore-3.1). With [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netcore-3.1) and [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netcore-3.1) you can cancel asynchronous operation. But SimpleTcp which i found, don't take CanncellationToken.